# What's the relation between these clues?

Tags: word, cryptic-clues

Find the relation between these words a.k.a. clues in the sentences below:

> 1. Zombies prefer to stay beside elevators.
> 2. Evil country produces thousands of money.
> 3. I was eating fast food in that vehicle.
> 4. Just bought the pen refill with a low price.
> 5. He spent some pocket money in that carpet store.
> 6. Solving some math questions in the subway station.
> 7. Include some books with over a thousand pages.
> 8. Japanese weapon hanging on the wall.
> 9. Several of them are from our uncles.

> Hint: they are cryptic clues